# Magento 1.9 - Checkbox per product in cart - Save to quote

Tags: magento, cart, custom-attributes, quote

I like to add checkboxes for every product in the cart, so the client can decide wich product (balloons) he want to befill with helium. I'm unable to save the infomation to quote respectively to the sales_flat_order.. tables.

I followed this tutorial: http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/

By clicking on "Refrech Cart" the function **_updateShoppingCart()** from my **CartController** is called.

```
protected function _updateShoppingCart()
    {
                    $cartData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cart');
                    if (is_array($cartData)) {
                            $cart = $this->_getCart();
                            $quote = $cart->getQuote();
                            foreach ($cartData as $index => $data) {
                                    if (isset($data['qty'])) {
                                            $cartData[$index]['qty'] = $data['qty'];
                                    }
                                    if (isset($data['ballo_add_gas']) && $data['ballo_add_gas'] == 1) {
                                            $cartData[$index]['ballo_add_gas'] = $data['ballo_add_gas'];
                                    }
                            }

                            $cartData = $cart->suggestItemsQty($cartData);
                            MAGE::log($cartData);
                            $cart->updateItems($cartData)
                                ->save();

                    }
                    $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

    }
```

This function is called, properly. The Informations in $cartData are according to the log file are:

```
[70] => Array
    (
        [qty] => 5
        [ballo_add_gas] => 1
        [before_suggest_qty] => 5
    )
```

So that's ok. If I set a fix value for **qty** in this function , everything works as espected-> the cart is updated with the fix quantity. So my direction should be ok.

Unfortunately the **ballo_add_gas** value isn't saved to quote eg. database.

I've tried to save the value in app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php in the function **updateItems($data)**.

```
$item->setData('ballo_add_gas', $itemInfo['ballo_add_gas']);
```

But nothing happens.

Next, in **Gas\Model\Observer.php** I've created an function.

```
        public function salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute($observer)
    {
            $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $quoteItem->setBallo_add_gas($product->getBallo_add_gas());
            //$quoteItem->setBallo_add_gas(1); THIS WORKS
    }
```

This function should copy the informations. See config.xml

```
            <sales_quote_item_set_product>
            <observers>
                <XXX_Gas_Model_Observer>
                    <class>Mexan_Gas_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute</method>
                </XXX_Gas_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_item_set_product>
    </events>
```

And again config.xml

```
<fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote_item>
            <ballo_add_gas>
                <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
            </ballo_add_gas>
        </sales_convert_quote_item>
        <sales_convert_order_item>
            <ballo_add_gas>
                <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
            </ballo_add_gas>
        </sales_convert_order_item>
    </fieldsets>
```

When I change **$product->getBallo_add_gas()** to a fixed value **1** everything works fine. So I assume when I'm able to save the value in **_updateShoppingCart()** properly. Than everything should be ok.

By the way. I've created the column **ballo_add_gas** in the database tables sales_flat_order_item and sales_flat_quote_item.

--
Another approach I followed was saving the Information directly into the DB.

```
private function saveGas($item_id, $gas)
    {
            $cartItem = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemById($item_id);
            $cartItem->setBalloAddGas($gas);
            $cartItem->save();

            $sales_flat_quote_item_table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_quote_item');
            $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
            $qry = "UPDATE " . $sales_flat_quote_item_table . " SET ballo_add_gas=" . $gas . " WHERE item_id=".$item_id;

            MAGE::log($qry);
            $db->query($qry);
    }
```

The information was saved to the DB, but disappeared after reloading the cart, and well there should be an easier way?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: hi, have you added the column ballo_add_gas to sales_flat_quote_item? for me your code looks a bit complicated, i've done something similiar and added a new column in sales_flat_quote_item and then ive overwritten the updateShoppingCart function.

Comment: hi, yes I've added the column to sales_flat_order_item and sales_flat_quote_item. Can you post your updateShoppingCart function?

Comment: I am maybe long after the post but are you sure about the existence and the visibility of the attribute at the different steps of the checkout process ?